# Inserting an item into an observable collection at index zero within a loop only works on the first iteration

Tags: c#, observablecollection

Having filled an ObservableCollection with some data I would like to pad it out if the data set isn't large enough to fill my graph.
To do this I am inserting data at index zero within a loop so the padding is always at the beginning of the collection.
The first iteration works well but the next iteration fails with an

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
```

What am I missing?

```
private void PadDataSet<T>(ObservableCollection<T> dataSet, DateTime minDataTimePeriod, int minuteIntervals)
{
    var paddedList = new List<DataItem>();
    var neededIntervals = _timescaleHours * 60 / minuteIntervals + 1;
    var actualIntervals = dataSet.Count();
    var padCount = neededIntervals - actualIntervals;
    for (var i = 0; i < padCount; i++)
    {
        var g = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        var item = g as DataItem;
        if (item != null)
        {
            item.TimePeriod = minDataTimePeriod.AddMinutes(-minuteIntervals * (i + 1));
            dataSet.Insert(0, g);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There does not seem to be anything wrong with the code excerpt. Repeated `Insert`s on the zero position should be ok. I suggest you look at the consumers of `CollectionChanged` event and see what happens to the collection there.

Comment: Thank you for the idea Marek but it doesn't seem to offer many clues. Within the collection changed event the new item does seem to have been added to index zero of the collection but following the debugger through, there are two get requests on the item and upon the second get, the exception is thrown.

Comment: What do you mean by "get" exactly? (I'd still bet on the event handler and related stuff, unless there is more to the insertion code than the excerpt in the original question.)

Comment: Sorry Marek, Its been a busy day. By "get" I mean the property getter of the item I was trying to add to my collection was being hit, multiple times. I think this is actually the problem and the "Index out of range" error is a red herring. Having changed the concept so the collection is always of a known type, the inserting to index zero works. Every time.